# Parse JSON in DB2

Tags: sql, json, db2

I am attempting to parse a JSON field in DB2. I am able to utilize JSON_VALUE and JSON_TABLE in Oracle without issue, but I am getting an error in DB2.

If I run this simple test in Oracle from DUAL it returns the currenttimestamp and 100.
When I try it in DB2 it returns the currenttimestamp, but an error for the JSON_VALUE. I have defaulted it to say 'Not Found', without that it is a null/blank value.

```
SELECT CURRENT TIMESTAMP AS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       JSON_VALUE('{a:100}', '$.a' DEFAULT 'Not found' ON ERROR) AS JSON_PARSE
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the error is caused by invalid JSON as input to [JSON_VALUE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-json-value). This works for me (with quotes around "a"):

```
SELECT CURRENT TIMESTAMP AS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       JSON_VALUE('{"a":100}', '$.a' DEFAULT 'Not found' ON ERROR) AS JSON_PARSE
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Is Oracle accepting invalid JSON objects?

Comment: Oracle does not seem to care whether there are quotes or not, it works both ways. This has given me something to work with though, thanks.